# any of the assignments

Tags: conditional-constructions, ambiguity, quantifiers

a. If you haven't done any of the assignments, I can give you extra time to do them.

Can this sentence mean two things?

1. If you have done none of the assignments, I can give you extra time to do them.
2. If there are some of the assignments that you haven't done, I can give you extra time to do them.

Many thanks.

Comment: No. *not any* means *none*.

Answer (score 1):

*Any of the assignments* would refer to all of the assignments as a whole. Which would imply that the setence is said in the context that,

> You have done none of the assignments. (1st option)

ANY is a Determiner. Hence, if a number was specified on the context of the assignments, it would have meant differently, as is in the 2nd option. For example:

> You haven't done any Two of the assignments....

Comment: To get the second meaning you could use "If there are any assignments that you haven't done"